# Adding slider to heatmap - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, slider, heatmap

I am dealing with a 3D double which I want to visualize slice by slice.
To do that, I tried plotting a heatmap and then adding a slider to select the index for the third dimension.
However, I get the following error:
`Error using uislider (line XX) HeatmapChart cannot be a parent.`

A minimal example to reproduce my problem:

```
% Generate dummy 3d array
img = ones(5,4,3);
for ii=1:size(img,3)
    img(:,:,ii)=ii;
end
% Try plotting heatmap with slider
h = heatmap(img(:,:,1));
uislider(h)
```

Is there actually a way/workaround to use a slider on a heatmap?
Thanks!

Comment: the `heatmap` is not a valid _container_ for the `uislider`. You have to attach the `uislider` to the parent `figure` or `panel`, then assign a callback function to the `ValueChangedFcn` property of the `uislider`. In this callback function, you can update the heatmap depending on the slider value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is. But I think you cannot use the uislider for this. Try:

```
h = heatmap(img(:,:,1));
uicontrol('Style','slider');
```

This slider has similar functionality, but doesn't look so nice. Still you can define Min, Max, Color, ... and also implement Callback function.

In the end it could look like:

```
h = heatmap(img(:,:,1));
uicontrol('Style','slider','Value',1,'Min',1,'Max',size(img,3),...
          'SliderStep',[0.5 0.5],'CallBack',{@SlideThroughSlices,img})

function SlideThroughSlices(slider,~,img)

   heatmap(img(:,:,slider.Value));

end
```

Assuming that the size of the third dimension of `img` is 3. Otherwise you have to adjust Min, Max and SliderStep.

Comment: Really cool! Had to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10452219/8552041) to be able to define the correct SliderStep, but otherwise it worked perfectly! First time using uicontrol :)

Comment: I would change the name of the callback function: `slice` is already a buit-in MATLAB function which you might not want to overload given you are already working with _slices_.

Comment: @Hoki, good idea, didn't know that it was a bult-in function, thanks

Comment: @nespereira Anytime :) Also on the MATLAB page you find good information about uicontrol (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html). If you try to display your current value of the slider and struggle with that, just let me know and I help you.